# Is wait_for_completion_timeout 100% fair?

Tags: multithreading, linux-kernel

Is it 100% guarantied that a thread which got first to wait_for_completion_timeout would wake up first when calling to complete?
Maybe I am wrong but I look at the following scenario:
thread A calls wait_for_completion_timeout and goes to sleep. when complete is called it wakes up and completes execution of `timeout = action(timeout);` in function do_wait_for_common.
Now lets say that another thread B calls wait_for_completion_timeout. now x->done is 1 so this thread sets x->done to 0 and goes on with its execution. Now thread A continues its execution, it goes to the next line:

```
} while (!x->done && timeout);
```

and goes back to sleep.
And so thread B executed first although thread A started waiting first.

Can someone please tell me what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not missing anything. Threads aren't at war, they cooperate to make forward progress. Being strictly fair has a significant cost, and since it's almost never needed, there's no reason to pay that cost in the general case.

It's generally most efficient to run the thread that was most recently running, since much of its data may still be in cache. So every thread benefits from an "unfair" policy.

Comment: In this case the following comment for function complete is kind of wrong: "This will wake up a single thread waiting on this completion. Threads will be awakened in the same order in which they were queued." Although technically thread B did not get to actual sleeping, from the point of view of the user, who used wait_for_completion_timeout thread B should wake up after thread A woke up.

Comment: The order in which the threads wake up does not guarantee the order in which they'll make forward progress anyway.